# Company owned devices options for system apps

Tags: system-apps

My questions regard the possibility to temperate which phone application could be set up while using Google Workspace (or any other [MPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_management)). Specifically: can I set up an application to replace the phone system app?

I've read [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7292363) but does that means that I can't disable the phone system app? Or that the `com.android.phone` package **is** the system app.

Another solution would be to get controls over the default apps settings and lock the employee out of these ones. The MPA solution would then be able to enforce the use of another Phone App as being the default system one. I could not find any documentation covering this.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of https://support.google.com/a/answer/7292363 is that

`com.android.phone` **is a system app that cannot be disallowed**

However you can create a [policy which will prevent non-emergency calls](https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements#4.24.-system-radio-management_1):

> 4.24. System radio management
>
> 4.24.5. IT admins can configure whether the device can make outgoing phone calls, excluding emergency calls (see outGoingCallsDisabled).

At which point you can [put your own Phone app on the device](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom). Note limitations on Phone apps that developers are bound to.

So presumably the device will still have the Google phone app but that app can only be used to call emergency services.

Comment: Nice, that would do for outgoing calls but still, that doesn't mean I can enforce incoming calls to be answered only through a phone app replacement, an employee could still modify the default app settings to choose the system one.

Comment: I was under the impression that your devices would be using a VoIP system, https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/network-telephony.html#third-party_apps_must_implement_connectionservice, but if its over a mobile voice network, the mobile provider should have audit capability and perhaps even some controls.

Comment: I can't use VoiP here, the project is for a financial institution which, due to some regulations, is forbidden to treat calls over the Internet, so the solution I need to provide is SIM-based only. Tuning the mobile provider would mean something entirely different. What I'd need is this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService#becoming-the-default-phone-app with no turning back (except at an admin level)